# Columns in ListView

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to display a list with the textblocks in the first column and the textboxes in the second column. However, when I use this code it displays a list with the textblocks displayed OVER the textboxes. Please show me what I am doing wrong.

```
<HubSection x:Uid="HubSection1" Header="Last Week">
    <DataTemplate>
       <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}">
           <ListView.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <StackPanel >
                       <Grid Height="26" Width="500" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                           <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                               <ColumnDefinition Width="175" />
                               <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                           </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                       </Grid>
                       <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Width="175" FontSize="24" Text="{Binding Date, Converter={StaticResource DateToStringConverter}}" />
                       <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Width="100" FontSize="24"  Text="{Binding Worked, Converter={StaticResource HoursToStringConverter}}" />
                   </StackPanel>
               </DataTemplate>
           </ListView.ItemTemplate>
       </ListView>
   </DataTemplate>
</HubSection>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Textblock/Textbox Controls are defined outside of the Grid, just in the StackPanel.

Just put them into the Grid.

```
<HubSection x:Uid="HubSection1" Header="Last Week">
<DataTemplate>
   <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}">
       <ListView.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <Grid Height="26" Width="500" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="175" />
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                   <!--Here-->
                   <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Width="175" FontSize="24" Text="{Binding Date, Converter={StaticResource DateToStringConverter}}" />
                   <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Width="100" FontSize="24"  Text="{Binding Worked, Converter={StaticResource HoursToStringConverter}}" />
               </Grid>
           </DataTemplate>
       </ListView.ItemTemplate>
   </ListView>
```

Comment: Duh! Thank you so much. I'll look much closer next time.